# Moving shape over imageview?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to find a way to implement a shape (a rectangle) that can be moved over an image. The user would drag the rectangle to an area in the image, as to eventually select it.

How can this be done? What should I use? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use canvas

```
    choosenImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosenImageView);

    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); //Bitmap
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBitmapPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    choosenImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```